# btrfs check repair fails - root item with more recent gen

Tags: linux, btrfs

How can I fix the following error please:

btrfs check -b --repair /dev/sdb2

enabling repair mode

WARNING:

```
Do not use --repair unless you are advised to do so by a developer

or an experienced user, and then only after having accepted that no

fsck can successfully repair all types of filesystem corruption. Eg.

some software or hardware bugs can fatally damage a volume.

The operation will start in 10 seconds.

Use Ctrl-C to stop it.
```

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Starting repair.

Opening filesystem to check...

Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb2

UUID: b5e07514-ad87-47ac-b4f7-3d797cb689bd

[1/7] checking root items

root 258 has a root item with a more recent gen (118911) compared to the found root node (118707)

ERROR: failed to repair root items: Invalid argument

Comment: Congratulations, you have probably destroyed the last chance of recovering that filesystem. Restore from backup.